# how to fix Error TF30063: You are not authorized to access VS2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I changed my password for my TFS. But when I try to reconnect I receive the TF30063 unauthorized error.

There are many issues like this and I tried everything I could find from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685111/error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-defaultcollection) and other forums

- Solve this issue by using the VS browser
- The right click on the connection
- The windows 10 manage user accounts edit and even the remove
- Deleted every VS cache file from appdata
- Deleted the whole connection in VS & tried to readd a new one
- Deleted all my Internet explorer cookies, passwords cache etc.

None of them work... Can't figure out what the issue is.

PS: it works within the browser.

Comment: if anyone gets the same error, pls vote on VS fix here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/devops-auth-prompt-hangs-vs2022-preview/1651650

Answer (score 34):

It should be a Visual Studio 2017 credential cached token issue. You could try below ways to clear cache:

1. Close all Visual Studio instances.
2. Delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService.

There are some identity related caching going on in there, deleting the folder will force the identity system to rebuild its cache.

- Also Clear TFS  related caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`
- Run Visual Studio as another user:

  `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`

  `runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe`

  Enter the user password, then `Team Explorer` > `Manage Connections`

If the issue still exists, also take a look at this [blog](http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2017/04/vs2017-unable-to-login-failed-to-refresh-access-token/) for more ways.

Comment: Thanks! I just deleted "%LOCALAPPDATA%/.IdentityService" and "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache" and it worked!

Comment: Bingo! Deleting `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache` fixed it immediately. (I didn't have an IdentityService folder)

Comment: PowerShell: `rm -Recurse $env:LOCALAPPDATA\.IdentityService;
rm -Recurse "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Team Foundation\*\Cache"`

Comment: If you're like us, having this issue so many years later, please note that the name change from TFS to Azure DevOps is important. The cache folder that you need to delete can now be something like `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Azure DevOps\8.0\Cache`.

Answer (score 14):

Based on developer community there is a timing issue during visual studio start up that can cause the Source Control Explorer window to grab and then hang on to an invalid version of the connection to your team project. Details visit developer community.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/93366/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-visualstu.html

Following work around steps help me to resolve the issue

1. Close all visual studio 2017
2. Start Visual studio 2017
3. If you see source control explorer at start up, then close source control explorer and Team explore and close visual studio 2017
4. Open visual studio 2017, ensure no source control explorer opened at start up
5. Go to View menu and click on team explorer
6. Then connect to TFS server.

Comment: oddly this worked when I had recently changed my credentials to our TFS server

Comment: This still worked with Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I will be facing this issue every six times a year. Because domain account password gets expired every 2 months 0 days or 8 weeks 5 days or 61 calendar days interval due to business security policy.

Follow these steps to change/set Password of TFS from IDE

1. Delete `TeamExplorer.config` from
   `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxxxxxx\Team Explorer`.
   (So after establishing a successful connection, it'll try to recreate
   again with the same data)
2. Add or change the TFS account Credential from Windows Credential Manager.
    So it won't prompt to enter a password again whenever when a connecting is established from IDE to TFS
3. If the above doesn't work close the Visual Studio IDE.
    Delete all the files inside `%LocalAppData%\.IdentityService` and `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache` and 
    on elevated prompt execute `runas /netonly /user:<user domain account> devenv.exe` navigating from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<Professional>\Common7\IDE\"`

[image]

[image]

Comment: i get the same error, pls vote on VS fix here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/devops-auth-prompt-hangs-vs2022-preview/1651650?from=email

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten the above error (TF30063: You are not...) numerous times and the following three resolutions worked for me at different times:

1. Simplest: I've seen "Source Control Explorer" referenced numerous times, but I never leave that open. I resolved the above error by closing Team Explorer and reopening. I then loaded my solution, and then reopened Team Explorer. It opened without issues and I could contact the server (ie, I ran a code comparison in the Solution Explorer on a file I'd edited) -VS Pro 2017 v 15.8.0
2. Middle complexity:
   I was able to reconnect with the following steps:
   -Open Team Explorer (View menu => Team Explorer)
   -Click "Manage Connections" which is the plug shaped button at top
   -Click the text "Manage Connections" which is actually a drop down menu
   -Select "Connect to a Project"
   This brings up a new window that shows hosted repositories for your account. After several seconds the window displayed the desired projects. I just had to click the desired one and click the "Connect" button at the bottom. Once I did this, I was able to access all TFS features (ie I checked in some work) -VS Enterprise 2017 v15.9.3
3. Last resort:
   I loaded VS2017 Community onto another machine and logged in on that machine using my regular login. I'm not sure why, but as soon as I logged in on this new installation my other two computers had no problem connecting. No additional steps were needed, though I may have restarted VS on those machines.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and the solution I finally found was when VS asked if this was a "Work or school account" or a "Personal account" I chose "Personal account", and that fixed it even though it is a work account.  This used to work fine, but it seems with some recent updates it causes an issue if you select "Work or school account"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with VS2017, version 15.9.4.

Common fixes are detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276188/visual-studio-2017-how-to-fix-error-we-could-not-refresh-the-credentials-for) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188210/clear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017). And the majority of pages talking about this problem reference those solutions or sub-sets in some combination or another. (And often to fix login bugs introduced in one of the 15.5.* versions of VS2017)

None of those solutions worked for me either and after researching for 2 days, I found a couple of fringe-reasons why VS 2017 will not refresh/store credentials.

The 2 main "fringe" problems/fixes I've found are:

1. [Connecting through certain proxy setups](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/140936/cannot-login-to-vs2017-1.html)
2. [Cryptography store not allowing for local storage](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/7i3opn/solved_windows_10_vpn_the_requested_operation/), see also [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178325/the-computer-must-be-trusted-for-delegation-and-the-current-user-account-must)

For myself it was the second problem, a good indicator of the issue is a log entry in `%TEMP%\servicehub\logs` with the error: "The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation."

It might also be a Windows 7/8.1 [known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3000850/november-2014-update-rollup-for-windows-rt-8-1-windows-8-1-and-windows) carried over to Windows 10 upgraded machines. The problem only happened on a machine that joined the domain **after** doing the Windows 10 upgrade.

**The fix is to add the following registry entry:**

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb]
"ProtectionPolicy"=dword:00000001
```

Setting that immediately fixed the issue with VS2017 connecting to the Microsoft Account. (And some other applications that would not persist credentials between launches)

Answer (score 0):

After you have tried making changes to default browser and installing new browser like firefox or chrome, if still doent work, then you might have to check with network team of your organization on proxy settings that should be  allowed in internet options. We have tried the above and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this only happened to me but I always used the wrong credentials (wrong username or wrong password). On Windows 11 I was only using my PIN, so it took automatically a user and password. I had to use different credentials to change my name and password.