# Unable to sign in windows azure account using Visual studio 2013 after changing password

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I have just changed my Azure portal login password as it was about to expire in next 4 days. After this when I tried to deploy my cloud service VS 2013 ask **"ReEnter Credentials your Credentials"**, After entering new credentials it keep asking me **ReEnter your credentials** also No subscription shows.
I tried to log in via Server Explorer also but the same problem occurs with **Object Reference not set to an instance of an object** error.
Can anyone have the solution of this?
Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, i used the new one. I checked in VS 2013 15 and 17, a similar issue in all these versions.

Comment: Do any of the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188210/clear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749709/how-to-fix-error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-vs2017/54017137 work?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this before on VS2015, the following worked for me:

- Reboot and sign in (to ensure there are no processes locking relevant files)
- Delete the folder %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService
- Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager and removing associated web and windows credentials
- Delete the contents of %temp%

If that fails, try running Visual Studio as administrator and sign in again.

Comment: Still not working. Adding to my problem, We have integrated Okta SSO to the Azure portal login.

Comment: Is this error happening on other similar machines too? Is your Visual Studio patched to the latest?

Comment: yes, I tried this on my colleague's machine too but similar issue found. Although I observed a very strange behavior, let's say I have two accounts one is my personal and another is company account. So if I previously logged in to my personal one and then add the company account, In this scenario it shows error while loading subscription error.  I tried login in VS 2017 where no account was added, and it seems ok there, the subscription also loaded correctly. I suspected there might be an issue with the Cache but after clearing all those, No relief.