# How to fix: we need to refresh the credentials for this account in VS 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-active-directory, okta, azureportal

I am using VS Community 2013 and I have just changed password of azure portal. I have integrated azure portal to Okta. Now, I want to publish my azure application. However, when I try to publish and adding account with credentials it is prompting reenter your credentials again and again. I am not able to proceed because of this. Could anyone help me to proceed?

[ScreenShot of issue]

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124620/unable-to-sign-in-windows-azure-account-using-visual-studio-2013-after-changing

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I have already tried the above mentioned solutions. They didn't work for me. Finally, I migrated my solution from 2013 to 2017.