# Visual Studio 2017.5: We could not refresh the credentials for the account. No Home Tenant found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-account

After installing the .5-Update for Visual Studio 2017, I'm unable to login to my work- or school-account. I'm getting the following instead
[image] .

I've tried the fix for the ["Failed to Refresh Access token"-Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276188/visual-studio-2017-how-to-fix-error-we-could-not-refresh-the-credentials-for) but that did'nt fix it...

Comment: Might want to also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188210/clear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749709/how-to-fix-error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-vs2017/54017137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out removing the account and adding it again fixed the issue in this case. It probably had something to do with the Personal Account, that was present as well.

Answer (score 0):

launch developer command prompt for VS 2017 from start menu
try to run Devenv.exe /ResetUserData.
This should fix the issue.