# Problem with authorization in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: authorization, visual-studio-2019

Recently I've found this problem after Visual Studio 19 trial period had ended.

[image: Image with problem]

I tried to change the embedded web browser to the system web browser, disable the Firewall, delete .IdentityService - and nothing helped. Finally, I reinstalled VS19 and nothing. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2017 - How to fix error: We could not refresh the credentials for the account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276188/visual-studio-2017-how-to-fix-error-we-could-not-refresh-the-credentials-for)

Comment: None of those answers helped me