# AcquireTokenException : we need to refresh credential for this account

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, visual-studio-2019, multi-factor-authentication

I am unable to login to my Visual Studio 2019 and I get the warning message `We need to refresh the credentials for this account`

Based on input from [Visual Studio 2017 - How to fix error: We could not refresh the credentials for the account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276188/visual-studio-2017-how-to-fix-error-we-could-not-refresh-the-credentials-for) , I have deleted the folder `"C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\.IdentityService"` but it did not resolve the issue

I have checked the logs and I see below message

> > AcquireTokenException: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access

I am using `Microsoft Authenticator` app to authenticate the request but `refresh` error keep pops in even though I successfully authenticate myself.

Note: I have `ZScalar` as firewall. I have even tried switching off `ZScalar`, but no luck